# Determine dvd movie title on Linux command line

Tags: linux, dvd

This is kind of a follow up on [How can I find the movie name with HandBrake CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/1005895/how-can-i-find-the-movie-name-with-handbrake-cli) which never got a satisfying answer.

On a headless server (centOS 7.5), I would like to find out the name of the movie which is on the dvd in the dvd drive, e.g. "Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels". The method should be suitable for embedding in a script, it should not require user interaction.

Anything goes, cli tools, python libs, C code, ...

Comment: It might be of interest to you for this that DVD's utilize a filesystem called the 'Universal Disk Format'.  This includes a volume name in the metadata, which usually ends up being at least a clipped form of the title of the movie.  Linux can technically read this filesystem, but support is not particularly great.

Comment: I actually found a solution with the help of the HandBrake Forum. I posted it as solution to the original question, because it is a solution that uses HandBrake. Should I post it here too, or just delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

I use lsdvd.  Note that some DVD's have bad title information though.